# Send an email to the author when a post is published

Tags: php, wordpress, email, post, author

Ι want to send email to author when post is published.

The code i have

```
add_action( 'publish_post', 'send_notification' );
 function send_notification( $post_id ) {    
    $post     = get_post($post_id);
    $content = $post->post_content;
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
    $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
    $post_url = get_permalink( $post_id );
    $post_title = get_the_title( $post_id ); 
    $author   = get_userdata($post->post_author);
    $subject  = '$post_title';
    $message .= "<a href='". $post_url. "'>'".$post_title."'</a>\n\n";
    $message .= $content;
    wp_mail($author->user_email, $subject, $message ); 
}
```

The email goes normally to the author  but he reads source code of the post content.

What should I do to get the author the post  by email normally and not the code from the post

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `wp_mail` function sends plain text emails which explains the post html tags aren't converted.

To send an html email you need to specify the headers:

```
add_action( 'publish_post', 'send_notification' );
 function send_notification( $post_id ) {    
    $post     = get_post($post_id);
    $content = $post->post_content;
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
    $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
    $post_url = get_permalink( $post_id );
    $post_title = get_the_title( $post_id ); 
    $author   = get_userdata($post->post_author);
    $subject  = $post_title;
    $message .= "<a href='". $post_url. "'>'".$post_title."'</a>\n\n";
    $message .= $content;
   $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    wp_mail($author->user_email, $subject, $message, $headers ); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks gael.Email now is send normal.Thankyou very much.I vote up but i'm new here and vote doesn't  show here

Comment: I m not new here but I never asked a question (here :/). I guess you have the ability to mark the question as Answered with the green check cross